# I'm trying to do a print statement for a list of items, each on a new line using \n but i keep getting syntax error. I can't find the problem

Tags: python, printing, python-3.7

I did a print statement to print a list of items each on a new line.
The print statement from line 1 works fine and list things with their variables.

For line three I want to do the same but without variables, so just a numbered list with the strings I entered.

It gives me a syntax error, I don't know why, it looks fine to my baby programmer eyes.

I tried adding a random after each comma variable because the first print statement I did worked with variables like this.

```
print ("\n1. the name of your guild is:\t", guild, "\n2. your name is:\t\t", player_1, "\n3. first guild members name is:\t", player_1, "\n4. second guild members name:\t", player_2, "\n5. third guild members name:\t", player_3)

print ("\nyou will need to visit some vendors to equip your guild for questing! "

print ("\nyou will need to buy:", "\n1. armour for all your guild members", "\n2. swords for all your guild members", "\n3. health potions", "\n4. mana potions", "\n5. stamina potions", "\n6. horses and saddles")
```

I am expecting it to go you will need to buy:

1. armour for all your guild members
2. swords for all your guild members
3. health potions
4. [etc...]

Comment: Please provide the traceback for your syntax error.

Comment: The second print is not closed

Comment: Ya i totally missed the 2nd line not being closed. Guess i still need experience looking for errors! Thanks!